# Dated of or dated from?

Tags: word-choice

Should I use 'dated of' or 'dated from' talking about a date in documentation? Here is an example: Decision of the Presidium of the Higher Attestation Commission of Ukraine dated of (dated from) 22 December 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think either is correct.

> Decision of the Presidium of the Higher Attestation Commission of Ukraine dated the 22 December 2010.

would be more normal.

The phrase *date from* is used in a different context. You might say

> His success dates from the time when he appointed a new coach.

I do not think *date of* is used at all in a verbal sense but as Ronald Sole points out in a comment if *date* is a noun then we do have other possibilities.

> The date of the next election
> The date on which Easter falls in 2021

Comment: You could write **the date of his birth / death etc**

Comment: You could also say "Decision...of the 22nd of December 2010".

Comment: @RonaldSole I must have been fixated on the verb date and missed that completely. I have taken the liberty of updating using your suggestion. Thanks.